# What does @ means when it is at the start of a registry value data?

Tags: windows, registry

When looking at windows registry values, some of the data starts with an @. I have not been able to find any information on what the @ stands for.

Comment: The @ has no special meaning on its own. Any meaning is applied by the code that read/writes it. It's like asking, "My library book has a green sticker on it. What does that mean?" The book publisher doesn't know what that means. The sticker manufacturer doesn't know. Only your library knows. And you didn't say which library you got the book from.

Comment: [Using Registry String Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/intl/using-registry-string-redirection); used as well for extracting  MUI verbs or icons  from a resource file.

Comment: @JosefZ Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for. I figured it might be have been a redirection tag of some sort.